# Why is have_posts() : the_post() not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display the all post in table With my plugin . I already have three post but following code doesn't display anyting .

**CODE OF PLUGIN PAGE :**

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?><?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
               <tr>
                  <td id="username"><?php the_title(); ?></td>

                  <td>
                      <video class="video" width="200" height="100">
                        <source src="<?php echo $rs->user->profile_video;?>" type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser does not support the video.
                      </video>
                </td>
                  <td id="status"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"></a></td>
                  <td><select class="action">
                      <option>-Select-</option>
                      <option value="1" >Active</option>
                      <option value="0">Inactive</option>
                      <option value="edit">Edit</option>
                      <option value="4">Delete</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>


<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

> Where I have done My Mistake ???

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you run a wp_query or a query_posts before the loop?

Comment: no . I think its not effect on have_post();

Comment: If you are creating your own post list, it needs to have a query_posts before the loop. Otherwise it doesn't know what to list.

Comment: thanks .. `query_posts();` ..works

Comment: @rnevius On frontend that's true, but I'm not sure that stands on the admin side. On the admin side you don't always have a default query running (as this very case demonstrated it)

Comment: why  ?? @rnevius `WP_Query()` or `get_posts()` is not working

Comment: WP_Query would work, if you do this: `$wq = new WP_Query($args); while $wq->have_posts(): $wq->the_post(); endwhile;` - see my answer below

Comment: I think this deserves a +1 simply for using Linux :P

Comment: ha ha  .. Nice .. you also deserve +1 for make me smile

Answer (score 2):

You can use WP_Query to retrieve your posts. WP_Query is a class and its constructor will return an object, which also has the loop functions.

Notice the `$wq` variable and `$wq->have_posts()`, etc.

Important: for the functions called inside the loop (`the_title()`, `the_content()`, `the_permalink()`, etc.) **don't** prepend the `$wq` variable. They work as they would with `query_posts()`

```
<?php 
    $wq = new WP_Query($args); // $args are the same as the args for query_posts()
?>

<?php if ($wq->have_posts()) : ?><?php while ($wq->have_posts()) : $wq->the_post(); ?>
               <tr>
                  <td id="username"><?php the_title(); ?></td>

                  <td>
                      <video class="video" width="200" height="100">
                        <source src="<?php echo $rs->user->profile_video;?>" type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser does not support the video.
                      </video>
                </td>
                  <td id="status"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"></a></td>
                  <td><select class="action">
                      <option>-Select-</option>
                      <option value="1" >Active</option>
                      <option value="0">Inactive</option>
                      <option value="edit">Edit</option>
                      <option value="4">Delete</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>


<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Not working any more  .. This is working with `query_posts()` only

Comment: NOT WORKING : `$wq = new WP_Query($args=null);
?><?php if ($wq->have_posts()) : ?><?php while ($wq->have_posts()) : $wq->the_post(); 
      `

Comment: WORKING :`query_posts($arg=null);
?><?php if (have_posts()) : ?><?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); `

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,

when i used print_r($wq); 
i got a result, but have_posts() returned false

i fixed it for me using following code:

```
<?php
$args = array(
      'posts_per_page'   => -1,
      'offset'           => 0,
      'orderby'          => 'date',
      'order'            => 'ASC',
      'post_type'        => 'post',

    );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );

   foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
?>

<p>my html</p>

<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```